# TI J6: How to find if my application is using GPU

Tags: qt, gpu

I am trying to make use of the GPU present in TI Jacinto 6 target. I have compiled the QT5 opengl examples. I am able to run the qt5 opengl examples on TI J6. Now, I want to know if the application running is GPU accelerated or not. How can I find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt doesn't magically GPU-accelerate the entire application. Widgets are not accelerated unless they derive from [`QOpenGLWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html). Qt Quick 2 is accelerated by default; there's an option of using the software renderer on hardware that doesn't support OpenGL ES 2. Qt Quick 1 is accelerated if you set a `QOpenGLWidget` as a viewport on the `QGraphicsView`.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the application with QSG_INFO=1 in the environment. This will print Qt Scene Graph logs on the console including which render loop is used. To find whether hardware acceleration is used, check the GL_VENDOR and GL_RENDERER prints in the Qt Scene Graph log. For example, on TI Jacinto 6 platform, following are the logs:

> QSG: texture atlas dimensions: 2048 x 1024
>
> R/G/B/A Buffers:    8 8 8 8
>
> Depth Buffer:       24
>
> Stencil Buffer:     8
>
> Samples:            0
>
> GL_VENDOR:          Imagination Technologies
>
> GL_RENDERER:        PowerVR SGX 544MP
>
> GL_VERSION:         OpenGL ES 2.0 build 1.9@2253347

Above logs show that OpenGL ES 2.0 version is used with GPU PowerVR SGX 544MP.